# how to call another method component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I would like render workload method learningHour after the setStatusofuser() method in confiramation.ts how can I do that can someone help please.

this is my confirmation.ts component

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { courses } from '../models/courses';
import { CoursesService } from '../services/course.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmation',
  templateUrl: './confirmation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirmation.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmationComponent implements OnInit {
  msg: string = '';
  condition:boolean;
  courseList: Array<courses>;

  constructor(private courseService: CoursesService,  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
  public dialog: MatDialog,) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }
  getAllCourses(){
    this.courseService.getAllCourses('PATKRISH').subscribe((data) => {
      this.courseList = data;
      console.log(this.courseList);
    });
  }
  setStatusOfUser(){
    this.courseService.setStatus(this.data.courseId,'PATKRISH').subscribe((data)=>{
      this.msg=data;
      this.getAllCourses()
     
    })
    this.condition=true;
    this.courseService.getAllCourses('PATKRISH').subscribe((data) => {
      this.courseList = data;
      console.log(this.courseList);
    });
  
  }

}
```

after setStatusOfUser() method I want render workload component learningHours method

workload.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WorkloadService } from '../services/workload.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-workload',
  templateUrl: './workload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workload.component.css']
})
export class WorkloadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private workloadService:WorkloadService) { }

  workload:number=0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.learningHours()
  }
  learningHours (){
    this.workloadService.getWorkloadPercentage("PATKRISH").subscribe(
      data => {
        if(data==0){
         this.workload=0;
        }else{
          this.workload=data;
        }
        console.log(data);
      },
      error=>{console.log(error);
      this.workload=0;}
    );
  }

}
```

course.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { courses } from '../models/courses';

// import { AddProgress } from '../interface/progress';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    
  }),
};
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CoursesService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  // http://localhost:8080/api/addassignment/coursebyuserid/PERAVIKA
  getAllCourses(userId: any): Observable<courses[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<courses[]>(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/addassignment/coursebyuserid/${userId}`
    );
  }
  setStatus(courseId: any, userId: any): Observable<string> {
    return this.httpClient.put<string>(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/addassignment/${courseId}/${userId}`,
      httpOptions
    );
  }
}
```

workload.sevice.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WorkloadService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getWorkloadPercentage(id: string): Observable<number> {
    return this._http.get<number>(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/learningmeter/getmeter/PATKRISH`
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't call ngOnInit - it's a lifecycle method - the framework calls it when the component is initialized.

If you want the functionality that is in the ngOnInit method to happen at another time (other than initialization of the component), I suggest that you move it to another (non-lifecycle) method.

If you want that functionality both on initialization and at a later time, then you can call the new method from ngOnInit.